# MySQL Insert Float32 and Float64 Go

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to insert a row into a MySQL table:

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
    "os/exec"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
    temp_cpu := getCPUTemp() // returns float32
    temp_gpu := getGPUTemp() // returns float64

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@/sysStats")
    handleError(err)

    _, err = db.Query("INSERT INTO temperatures (id, cpu, gpu, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", 1, temp_gpu, temp_cpu, time.Now())
    handleError(err)

    db.Close()
    return
}
```

It builds successfully but when I run the resulting binary it just times out after a long time with a generic timeout error.

The table has the following schema:

```
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| idtemperatures | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cpu            | float     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gpu            | float     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp      | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am running this on the same server the MySQL instance is hosted and I can access the database with the user/password from the terminal.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: The id field in your db is called `"idtemperatures"` and you used `"id"` in your SQL statement.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, it is late. But why is there no error message? I'm still learning Go and this has been the most frustrating part so far.

Comment: The lack of error is because you used `DB.Query()` but you really should've used `DB.Exec()`. See my edited answer for details on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id / primary key field in your db is called `"idtemperatures"` and you used `"id"` in your SQL statement.

Also since you're not executing a query (but an `INSERT`), you should use the [`DB.Exec()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec) method to execute it. You should never use [`DB.Query()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query)  to execute DML (Data Manipulation Language) statements.

You may get a timeout error if you can't connect to your database. Make sure it uses default protocol (TCP) and host (localhost:3306). Another reason may be because you used `DB.Query()` to execute your SQL `INSERT` statement, and `DB.Query()` returns an [`*sql.Rows`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows) value which holds a database connection until you close it with the [`Rows.Close()`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close) method - which you never do; you didn't even store the returned `db.Rows` value.

Also you should call `db.Close()` as a deferred statement, right after the error check after opening it.

Corrected example:

```
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@/sysStats")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to open DB:", err)
    return
}
defer db.Close()

s := "INSERT INTO temperatures (idtemperatures, cpu, gpu, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
res, err = db.Exec(s, 1, temp_gpu, temp_cpu, time.Now())

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to execute INSERT:", err)
} else {
    n, err := res.RowsAffected()
    fmt.Println("INSERT executed, rows affected: ", n, err)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I still get absolutely no output until the timeout occurs. I forgot to mention I am trying to run this on a raspberry pi with armv7l architecture. Not sure if that matters?

Comment: @DonaldJ It looks you can't connect to the db. Are you sure it uses default protocol (TCP) and host (localhost:3306)?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what is going on to be honest. I just compiled on a separate machine (x86_64) and pointed it at the LAN address of the mysql instance and it worked. I am marking your answer as correct and I will try to figure out what is wrong with the mysql instance config locally. Thanks!

Comment: For posterity I will add what I needed to finally fix the issue:
`db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:pass@unix(/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock)/sysStats?loc=Local")`