# How can I check whether Psql successfully updated the record in Go

Tags: go, pq

I use [this driver](https://github.com/lib/pq) to communicate with psql from Go. Now when I issue an update query, I have no possibility to know whether it actually updated anything (it can update 0 rows if such id is not present).

```
_, err := Db.Query("UPDATE tags SET name=$1 WHERE id=1", name)
```

I tried to investigate err variable (in the way the doc suggests for Insert statement):

```
if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
    ...
}
```

But even with non-existent id, err is still null.

I also tried to use QueryRow with returning clause:

```
id := 0
err := Db.QueryRow("UPDATE tags SET name=$1 WHERE id=1 RETURNING id", name).Scan(&id)
```

But this one fails to scan &id when id=1 is not present in the database.

---

So what is the canonical way to check whether my update updated anything?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [MySQL Insert Float32 and Float64 Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751165/mysql-insert-float32-and-float64-go)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using `db.Exec()` instead of `db.Query()` for queries that do not return results.  Instead of returning a `sql.Rows` object (which doesn't have a way to check how many rows were affected), it returns a `sql.Result` object, which has a method `RowsAffected() (int64, error)`.  This returns the number of rows affected (inserted, deleted, updated) by any write operations in the query fed to the `Exec()` call.

```
res, err := db.Exec(query, args...)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

n, err := res.RowsAffected()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
// do something with n
```

Note that if your query doesn't affect any rows directly, but only does so via a subquery, the rows affected by the subquery will not be counted as rows affected for that method call.

Also, as the method comment notes, this doesn't work for *all* database types, but I know for a fact it works with `pq`, as we're using that driver ourselves (and using the `RowsAffected()` method).

Reference links:

- https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Exec
- https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Result